# Solve in prime numbers the equation $p^q+q^r=r^p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Find all triples of prime numbers $(p,q,r)$ such that $$p^q+q^r=r^p.$$

I proved that when $r=2$, the equation becomes $$p^q+q^2=2^p.$$ Then I tried to use reciprocity laws and Fermat's little theorem. I could prove that $p\equiv 7\pmod 8$ and that $p>q$.

The equation appeared in some olympiad . They asked to prove that $r=2$. So I am trying to find at least one triple.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: The Equation seems really nice, and we can find $r$. But then...Bump

Comment: I think there is no such triple, But I couldn't prove it, I need a help of some experts

Comment: Write what you have tried and/or already found.

Comment: I think you may be right about no triple; I tried a few primes and none worked.

Comment: Notice that if p and q are both odd, then r has to be even (namely r=2). Otherwise either p or q is equal to 2. That should help

Comment: I proved that $r=2$. Then the equation becomes $$p^q+q^2=2^p$$. Then I tried to use reciprocity laws and Little Fermat's theorems. I could prove that $p\equiv 7\pmod 8$ and that $p>q$.

Comment: Edit your post to include this in your question body.

Comment: Where does the question come from? The source can give an indication of which methods can be useful, whether it is an open problem, etc

Comment: The equation appeared in some olympiad . They asked to prove that $r=2$. So I am trying to find at least one triple

Comment: @TynyshbekAnuarbekov You should directly add those clarifications to your question (I did it for you now).

Comment: I am confused @TynyshbekAnuarbekov. Do we already know that r=2 or that's actually the point to prove? That any possible solution must have r=2?

Comment: @MrRipstein You don't need to add `@` to notify OP.

Comment: And replying to myself, I assume he proved that for r<>2 there are no solutions so what is left is to find at least one solution with r=2. I think the only integer solutions are (p,q)=(0,1),(1,1) or (1,-1) so no triple

Comment: @MrRipstein If you take a look at the edit history, you'll know that the original version of the question is a PSQ, so we have nothing conclusive.  It's possible that $r = 2$ or $r \ne 2$.  The former seems easier to start with in order to give context to this problem, so that it won't get closed.

Comment: Related AoPS forum: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1639551, although it is just about showing $r=2$.

Answer (score 7):

It is clear that precisely one of $p$, $q$ and $r$ must equal $2$. We'll first show that in fact $r=2$:

---

**Observation 1:** $r=2$.

If $q=2$ then reducing mod $3$ shows that
$$p^2+2\equiv r^p\pmod{3},$$
so either $p=3$ or $r=3$. Both are easily verified to be impossible.

If $p=2$ then
$$2^q+q^r=r^2,$$
but for all primes $q,r>2$ we have $q^r>r^2$, a contradiction.

---

This leaves us with finding odd primes $p$ andd $q$ satisfying
$$p^q+q^2=2^p.$$
We first make a few more simple observations.

---

**Observation 2:** $q^2\equiv2\pmod{p}$.

By Fermat's little theorem
$$q^2\equiv p^q+q^2\equiv2^p\equiv2\pmod{p}.$$

**Observation 3:** $q<p$.

As $p>2$ we have $2^q<p^q+q^2=2^p$, so $q<p$.

---

The problem can be rephrased in the number ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. This is a unique factorization domain with unit group $\{\pm1\}$. Setting $m:=\frac{p-1}{2}$ we can rewrite the equation above as
$$p^q=-(q+2^m\sqrt{2})(q-2^m\sqrt{2}).$$
The greatest common divisor of the two factors on the right hand side divides both $2q$ and $p^q$. Because $p$ and $q$ are distinct, these two factors are coprime and so both are $q$-th powers in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Let $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$ be such that
$$q+2^m\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})^q.$$
Then $q-2^m\sqrt{2}=(a-b\sqrt{2})^q$ and hence
$$p^q=-(a+b\sqrt{2})^q(a-b\sqrt{2})^q=(2b^2-a^2)^q,$$
which shows that $p=2b^2-a^2$.

---

**Observation 4:** $a=\pm q$ and $b\mid2^m$. *(Thanks to barto's comment)*

Set $\alpha:=a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $\bar{\alpha}:=a-b\sqrt{2}$. Because
$$(\alpha+\bar{\alpha})\mid(\alpha^2+\bar{\alpha}^q)\qquad\text{ and }
\qquad(\alpha-\bar{\alpha})\mid(\alpha^2-\bar{\alpha}^q),$$
we see that $2a\mid2q$ and $2b\sqrt{2}\mid2^{m+1}\sqrt{2}$. The binomial expansion
$$q+2^m\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})^q,$$
shows that $q\mid a^q$, and hence that $q\mid a$ so $a=\pm q$.

**Observation 5:** $b=\pm1$.

By observation 3 we have $a^2=q^2<p^2$, and so
$$p=2b^2-a^2>2b^2-p^2.$$
Because $p>q>2$ we have $p\geq5$ and so $b^2<\frac{p^2+p}{2}\leq(p-1)^2$.
Also, by observation 2
$$p=2b^2-a^2=2b^2-q^2\equiv2b^2-2\pmod{p},$$
and so $b^2\equiv1\pmod{p}$. This means $b=\pm1$.

---

We have $a=\pm q$ and $b=\pm1$ and so
$$p=2b^2-a^2=2-q^2<0,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: +1 for nice progress, but $2^\sqrt{p}$ grows faster than $p$.  For example, $p=97<2^9<2^\sqrt{97}$

Comment: @Michael; you are absolutely right, I guess I needed a break ;) I'll update and hopefully complete the answer soon.

Comment: $p^q>p^{\sqrt{p}}>2^p$ for $p>16$. Also, we have not $q^3>r^2$, but $q^r\ge3^r>r^2$.

Comment: @didgogns The latter was a typo, thanks for noticing. The former I do not understand; this is already false for $p=17$, and in fact for every $p>16$. Maybe you considered the reverse inequality?

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake for that.

Comment: From $q+2^m\sqrt{2}=(a+b\sqrt{2})^q$ and binomial expansion it also follows that $q \mid a$, contradicting observation 6.

Comment: @barto Thank you, that completes the proof! I've taken the liberty of incorporating it to complete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So $$p^q+q^2=2^p \qquad(*)$$  It is easy to show that $\boxed{p\gt q}$ or just look at the graph of the function $x ^ y + y ^ 2 = 2 ^ x$ for $x,y\gt1$.

If $p=4n+1$ then from $(*)$,
$$q=4m\pm1\Rightarrow4N+1+16m^2\pm8m+1=2N+8m^2\pm4m+1=2^{p-1}\space\text{ absurde}.$$
Then $p$ must be of the form  $\boxed{p=4n-1}$.

Put $p=an-1$ where $n$ is odd and $a=2^r,\space r\ge 2$.
$$(an-1)^q=(an)^q-1+\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}(\pm1)^k\binom qk(an)^{q-k}$$ $$(an-1)^q=(an)^q-1+an\left(\sum_{k=1}^{q-2}(\pm1)^k\binom qk(an)^{q-k-1}\right)+anq$$
For $\boxed{q\equiv\pm1\pmod4}$ put $q=bm\pm1$ where $m$ is odd and $b=2^s,\space s\ge 2$.

The equation $(*)$ becomes
$$(an)^q+an\left(\sum_{k=1}^{q-2}(\pm1)^k\binom qk(an)^{q-k-1}\right)+anq+(bm)^2\pm2bm=2^p\qquad(**)$$ 
This last condition, , implies

Note that the sum $\left(\sum\right)$ is even.

Now

►if $a\le b$ (i.e. $2^r\le2^s$) then dividing by $a$ we are done because $nq$ is odd.

►if $a\gt b$ (i.e. $\dfrac {a}{2b}=2^{r-s-1}\ge1$) then dividing by $2b$ we are done for all $p,q$ such that $r\gt {s+1}$ because $m$ is odd.

It remains the cases for which $r=s+1$, in other words and taking into account the above
$$p=2^{s+1}n-1,\space q=2^sm\pm1\space n,m \space \text{ odds},\space \text {with }p\gt q$$
This last condition, $p\gt q$ , implies
$$2^{s+1}n-1\gt2^sm\pm1\Rightarrow\begin{cases}2^sn\gt2^{s-1}m+1\\2n\gt m\end{cases}$$ Thus it remains to study the equation where $p=2^{s+1}n-1,\space q=2^sm\pm1\space n,m \space \text{ odds},\space \text {with }p\gt q$ both odd primes.
$$\boxed{\displaystyle(2^{s+1}n-1)^{2^sm\pm1}+(2^sm\pm1)^2=2^{2^{s+1}n-1}}$$

I will return to the possible proof of this last part. If someone wants to end this problem by proving the apparently probable impossibility of solution, let it go forward. In particular if @Servaes wants to finish his very interesting partial answer.

Comment: I could prove that $q^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod (p^{2}) $ and $2^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod (q^{2}) $ , does it help?

Comment: Maybe. Go ahead to the possible end.