# Solve in prime numbers $p^q+q^2=2^p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Solve in prime numbers
> $$p^q+q^2=2^p$$

My progress:

Clearly by parity, we have either $p^q,q^2$ even or $p^q,q^2$ is odd.

**Case 1:** $p^q,q^2$ even

Then $q=2,$ so we get $p^2+4=2^p.$ Now, clearly $p=2$ doesn't satisfy. So, we assume $p$ is an odd prime.

Now, we take $\mod 8$ on both sides.

So the $RHS \equiv 0\mod 8$ but the $RHS \equiv 5 \mod 8.$ Not possible.

**Case 2:** $p^q,q^2$  odd

Now we take $\mod 3$ on both sides. We get $RHS \equiv 2\mod 3.$

Also, $q^2\equiv 0,1 \mod 3$ and $p^q\equiv 0,1,2 \mod 3.$ So we get either $p^q\equiv 2 \mod 3, q^2\equiv 0\mod 3$ or $p^q\equiv 1 \mod 3, q^2\equiv 1\mod 3.$

The first case implies, $p^3+9=2^p.$ Now, for $p\ge 10$ we start getting $ 2^p>>p^3+9.$
Hence, $p\le 10.$ Then putting $p=5$ We get that this doesn't satisfy.

Hence $\boxed{p\equiv 1 \mod 3, 3\nmid q}.$ Hence $p>3.$

We, then take $\mod 8$ on both sides.

We get $RHS\equiv 0\mod 3.$ Also odd squares are $1\mod 8.$ Hence $p^q\equiv 7\mod 8.$

Hence, $\boxed{p\equiv 7\mod 8,~~q^2\equiv 1\mod 8}.$

---

This was my progress, any hints/solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Knowing $p^q$:is even is enough to know $p$ is even.

Comment: One idea: Note that $p^q\equiv p\pmod q.$ So $2^p-p$ must be divisible by $q.$ Similarly, $2^p\equiv 2\pmod p,$ so $q^2-2$ must be divisible by $p.$ I don’t see where to go from there.

Comment: It's already been solved.(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786138/solve-in-prime-numbers-the-equation-pqqr-rp)